# struggling with checkboxes laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm struggling quite a bit with how to handle checkboxes in Laravel.
For a default unchecked value to come through with the inputs and have 0, I found this example:

```
<td class="text-center">
    {{Form::hidden('name', 0)}}
    {{Form::checkbox('name', 1)}}
</td>
```

This should only return 1 when checkbox is actually checked.
But to me it always returns 0.

What am I missing here?

Comment: [Check these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A741747+laravel+checkbox), if need more help please provide some more information.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in this direction. However I could not find the answer I was looking for. From my understanding, the default value is always 1 as set by the formbuilder, whether the checkbox is checked or not. I want to change this behaviour so that the input returns 0 when unchecked. I thought this might have been good way to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this router to test it and understand how to configure it properly:

```
Route::any('test', function() {

    echo 
        Form::open(array('url' => 'test')) .

        Form::checkbox('checkboxOne', 1, true).
        Form::label('This is a checkbox checked by default').
        "<br>".

        Form::checkbox('checkboxTwo', 999, false).
        Form::label('This is a checkbox unchecked by default').
        "<br>".

        Form::submit('go!').

        Form::close();

    dd(Input::all());

});
```

The value parameter has no meaning unless you check the box and post your form, then the checkbox name will have the value you set for it.

Comment: Thanks! For some strange reason the input kept returning 1, whether I checked or unchecked it. because I set the default in the second parameter myself, of course... thanks again!